# Row Number Generate Automatically for all pages continuously in grid view in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview, datagrid

I want to generate row number in gridview auotmatically for all pages continuously.
For EG: I have 3 pages on gridview of records 150. Each page contains 50 records.

> I want to display row number for all records in a grid from 1 to 150
>   continuously.

Here is my code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Row Number" ItemStyle-Width="100">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblRowNumber" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>' runat="server" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

It display row number on each page starting from 1 to 50 . I actually want number from 1 to 150 . Anyone please help me if you have any idea.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I applied the above code and the result was for eace page  the row number starting from 1 .but i want the row number continously.if the page one end with number 50 then page 2 first row number start with 51  but in my code it start with again number 1. @JohnB

Comment: If you use GridView `AllowPaging` and set the `PageSize` to 50, then `Container.DataItemIndex` will count accordingly. It seems that you are doing the paging yourself and bind 50 items at a time. Then it's no wonder it will never count beyond 50.

Comment: Yes . Is there any other alternate solution for this issue @VDWWD

Comment: Either use the build-in paging or don't use `ItemIndex` to display the row number, but create your own.

Comment: Without itemindex how to display row number @VDWWD

Answer (score 0):

I've found a bit of a hacky way to easily create the correct row numbers with the unused property `PageSize`. If you set that corectly then the row numbers will be correct and it won't affect anything since `AllowPaging` is set to false.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Row Number" ItemStyle-Width="100">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRowNumber" Text='<%# (Container.DataItemIndex + 1) + (GridView1.PageSize * 50) %>' runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Note that you have to set the PageSize value before binding data.

```
GridView1.DataSource = source;
GridView1.PageSize = 2;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: it is not working properly because the page size cannot be changed on front end Am using this on codebehind it works fine Thank You @VDWWD

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Text='<%# (GridView1.PageIndex * GridView1.PageSize) + Container.DisplayIndex + 1 %>'
```